# "Command not found" error with UNIX shell

Tags: c, shell, unix, compilation, pipe

I've been working on a C program which simulates a shell via the terminal. I'm stuck on the pipe where I use a temporary file.

My problem is that during the execution of a command like `ls | wc` it works 9 times on 10. Moreover if I execute this command in the terminal (real, not mine) about 1/10 of the time I get an error message that the wc command does not exist. Huh?

My code looks fine so I suspect the error is coming from my UNIX setup (terminal or core, I don't know). But I'm not sure. Does this look like a code error or an OS problem?

```
/**************************************/
/*           test parsing             */
/**************************************/

#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <errno.h>

char *delimiteurs = ";&<>|";
char *eltsCommande[10];
char *eltsoutput[10];
char *eltsinput[10];
char *eltstube[10];
char mot[50];
int symbole, status, c;

void parsing(){
    int i=0;
    int cmot=0;
    while(1){
        c = getchar();
        if      (c == '\n') {symbole = 0;return;}
        else if (c == ';')  {symbole = 1;return;}
        else if (c == '&')  {symbole = 2;return;}
        else if (c == '<')  {symbole = 3;return;}
        else if (c == '>')  {symbole = 4;return;}
        else if (c == '|')  {symbole = 5;return;}
        else if (c == EOF)  {symbole = 7;return;}
        else if (c != ' ') {
            symbole = 10;
            while(c != '\n' && !strchr(delimiteurs,c)){
                i=0;
                while(c != 32 ){
                    if((c != '\n') && !strchr(delimiteurs,c)){
                    mot[i]=c;i++;
                    c=getchar();
                    }
                    else {break;}
                }
                break;
            }
            while(c == ' ')
            {
                c=getchar();
            }
            ungetc(c,stdin);
            mot[i]=0;
            eltsCommande[cmot++]=strdup(mot);
            fflush(stdout);
            if(c == '\n' || strchr(delimiteurs,c))
            {
                eltsCommande[cmot]=0;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    pid_t pid, fid;
    int background = 0;
    int status;
    char car;
    int i, j, k, l;
    int p, p2;
    int execute=1;
    int output=0;
    int input=0;
    int tube=0;
    int fd[2];
    int fich;
    while(1){
        if(execute==1){
            if(symbole==0){
                printf("Entrez une commande> ");
            }    
            for (j=0;j<10;j++){
                eltsCommande[j]=NULL;
            }            
            execute=0;    
            background=0;
        }
        fflush(stdout);
        parsing();
        switch (symbole) {
            case 0 :                            // SYMBOLE : \n
                p=fork();
                for(k=0;k<10;k++){
                     printf("ELEMENT COMMANDE %d : %s \n", k, eltsCommande[k]);
                     //printf("ELEMENT COMMANDE TUBE %d : %s \n", k, eltstube[k]);
                     //printf("ELEMENT COMMANDE INPUT %d : %s \n", k, eltsinput[k]);
                     //printf("ELEMENT COMMANDE OUTPUT %d : %s \n", k, eltsoutput[k]);
                }

                if(p==0){                    //fils
                    if(tube==1){//printf("\n\n\n");
                              fich = open("fichtmp",O_RDONLY,0640);
                        close(0); //fermeture clavier
                        dup(fich); //fichier devient entrée 0
                        execvp(eltsCommande[0], eltsCommande);
                        close(fich); //fermeture fichier
                          }
                          else if(output==0 && input==0){        //pas de redirection
                          printf("truc1");
                        execvp(eltsCommande[0], eltsCommande);    
                    }else if(output==1){                //dans le cas d'une redirection
                    printf("truc2");
                        close(1);
                        int filew = creat(eltsCommande[0], 0644);
                        execvp(eltsoutput[0], eltsoutput);
                    }
                    else if(input==1){
                    printf("truc3");
                        close(0);
                        int filer = open(eltsCommande[0], O_RDONLY);
                        execvp(eltsinput[0], eltsinput);
                    }/*
                    if(tube==1){
                        int f2 = fork();
                        pipe(fd);
                        switch (f2){
                        case -1 : printf("loose");
                        case 0: close(fd[0]);
                            close(1);
                            dup(fd[1]);
                            close(fd[1]);
                                 execvp(eltstube[0], eltstube); break;
                               case 1: wait(&status);
                            close(fd[1]);
                            close(0);
                            dup(fd[0]); 
                            close(fd[0]);
                              execvp(eltsCommande[0], eltsCommande); break;
                          default : printf("err");
                          }*/
                    return 0;
                }else{                            //pere
                    if(background==0){                //pas de bg on attend le fils
                        waitpid(p, NULL, 0);
                    }                    
                    /*if(tube==1){
                        close(0);
                                dup(fd[0]);
                               close(fd[1]);
                              execvp(eltsCommande[0], eltsCommande);
                    }*/
                    output=0;
                    input=0;            
                    execute=1;
                    tube=0;
                }
                break;
            case 1:                                // SYMBOLE : ;
                p=fork();                        
                if(p==0){                         //fils
                    if(output==0 && input==0 && tube==0){        //pas de redirection
                        execvp(eltsCommande[0], eltsCommande);    
                    }else if(output==1){                //dans le cas d'une redirection
                        close(1);
                        int filew = creat(eltsCommande[0], 0644);
                        execvp(eltsoutput[0], eltsoutput);
                    }
                    else if(input==1){
                        close(0);
                        int filer = open(eltsCommande[0], O_RDONLY);
                        execvp(eltsinput[0], eltsinput);
                    }
                    return 0;                
                }else{                            //pere
                    waitpid(p, NULL, 0);    
                    output=0;
                    input=0;
                    execute=1;    
                }
                break;
            case 2:                                // SYMBOLE : &
                background=1;
                break;
            case 3:                                // SYMBOLE : <

                      if(input==0){
                          input=1;
                          execute=1;
                          for (l=0;l<10;l++){
                              eltsinput[l]=eltsCommande[l];
                          }
                      }
                      break;
            case 4:                                // SYMBOLE : >
                if(output==0){
                    output=1;
                    execute=1;
                    for (l=0;l<10;l++){
                        eltsoutput[l]=eltsCommande[l];
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 5:                                // SYMBOLE : |
                //if(tube==0){
                    /*for (l=0;l<10;l++){
                        eltstube[l]=eltsCommande[l];
                    }*/
                    p2=fork();
                    if(p2==0){
                        if(tube==0){
                            freopen( "fichtmp", "w", stdout );
                            execvp(eltsCommande[0], eltsCommande);
                        }
                        return(0);
                    }
                    else{    if(background==0){            // SANS MOD BG ATTENDRE FIN FILS
                            waitpid(p2, NULL, 0);
                        }
                        tube=1;                
                        execute=1;    
                    }

                break;
            default: 
                printf("");

        }
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Thank's for editing, it's pretty better right now of course. Sorry for my english.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Nice edit!

Comment: How is a program that simulates a shell different from a shell?

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand what you say. It's only a C program executed on a UNIX terminal which shall do like a shell (execute commands).

Comment: Hmmm, why not use an *actual* pipe instead of writing it to a temporary file?  Doing it your way, you have to wait for the first process to exit before delivering input.  That's not piping.

Comment: There is no error handling in your code so a missing command won't be detected. The only hint a command is not found is "truc<something>" is displayed on screen while this string is not displayed when the command exists due to improper flushing. How can you get the "wc command does not exist" message ? What OS are you running ?

Comment: @paddy Thank's for your answer. I know that the way i'm doing it isn't the best. But it runs 9/10 times. I'm actually only looking if it's an OS problem or programming mistake. I personnaly think that's is an OS problem. So if people can try this code and look if they get the error it will help me. Finally if it's an OS problem how can I fix it? I never saw this error on LINUX yet. When the profils will be fix, I will use pipe() command of course.

Comment: @jlliagre Sometimes when I'm executing "ls | wc" for example (it's only with wc and grep commandes) I get this error message (running on UNIX terminal not mine): Command 'wc' not found, was you looking for : wc or gwc. Command not found. I'm running on Ubuntu 12.10. When I'm running my personnal terminal I sometimes get no one print. That's why I think that's its one OS problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found from where come this problem.

Instead of a single space after the `|` I sometimes do an `Alt Gr + space` space, which isn't a valid space for the terminal. He tried to execute `(space)wc` instead of `wc` and that's why I got "command not found".

Thank you to all those who have studied the issue.